# How to execute a logic on finish button of docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

We have some fields to hide after the sign in DocuSign. When I tried to find a conditional logic on finish button of DocuSign, I couldn't find any suitable method. I couldn't find any suitable documentation either.

How to hide an element once we click on Finish button in DocuSign? I checked formulas, conditional rules and all possible options in API documentation.

Below is the requirement sample.

[image: Sample requirement image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to write a condition on the Finish button.

You can add conditional behavior to fields within the envelope to use during the signing session using conditional fields (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/conditional-fields/). For example, you can set it up such that selecting a checkbox would show another field for you to add additional information. But the Finish button itself is not something you can reference from the API

You also wouldn't be able to correct the envelope to modify fields that were assigned to a recipient that already signed